# Proper way of implementing generic methods for iterators

Tags: c++, oop, templates, virtual-functions

Let's say I want to do something like this (this is just an example of general idea):

```
class AbstractSortingMethod
{
     public:
     template<class iterator>
     virtual void Sort(iterator begin, iterator end) = 0;
};
```

which obviously is illegal in C++.

What's the proper design to achieve the same thing?

I know I can template class instead of templating the method, but this wouldn't allow for type deduction unless I implement some sort of factory-like method.

Another thing is - should I just "blindly trust" that the type that gets passed as template argument is an iterator?

**As per request in comments:**

There are probably many other (maybe even better) examples, but that's what I've come up with for now.

Let's imagine a program which is supposed to benchmark a performance of many different sorting methods in context of many different containers.

There's a class like SortingMethodTest that holds the unsorted data in many different containers (like list,regular array and vector etc.). We pass to it the sorting method functor, which inherits from something like AbstractSortingMethod mentioned earlier in this post. The benchmark procedure would look like this:

loop over all containers -> startTimer() -> pass the iterators of given container to sorting method and run it -> stopTimer() -> record time -> continue

Comment: Why do you need polymprophic behavior here? Why not use policy?

Comment: Could you provide an example of how this would be used?

Comment: "What's the proper design to achieve the same thing?" - what do you actually want to achieve? An abstract sorting method will require dynamic type deduction, which is likely to make the program difficult to maintain.

Comment: Likely you end with complicated 'type-elision'

Comment: @SergeyA I think it would make this less user-friednly. The user of class would have to specify container/iterator type in an explicit way.

Comment: @flatmouse same usage case as for template design pattern with additional "flavor" of it having to deal with iterators (which don't have any base type in C++)

Comment: @RichardHodges see my comment for flatmouse above

Comment: FWIW, if you really need this, you can use Boost.TypeErasure to create a "virtual iterator concept", where you specify the operations it needs to support (like a concept) and have the library generate a type that can act like any type that models that concept. For example, create a type called `AnyIterator` that supports `++it` and `*it` and it would store any type with those operations, using the type it was created with as implementations.

Comment: Can you provide examples of what you would use this for, assuming virtual member templates were possible?

Comment: @Barry see my comment for flatmouse

Comment: @user2521472 That's not at all clear. Can you, in the question, provide specific usages?

Comment: @user2521472, looks like  you are coming from Java background? C++ has a very different paradigm, and generally, we try to avoid run-time polymorphism whenever we can.

Comment: @SergeyA I write a lot in C# and a little bit in Java. I have some experience with C++, but I have only recently started to learn proper OOP concepts, which led me to new questions regarding the language and its "philosophy"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> loop over all containers -> startTimer() -> pass the iterators of given container to sorting method and run it -> stopTimer() -> record time -> continue

Based on this, you want templates, not polymorphism. You'll want a function template that takes the sorting algorithm and a pair of iterators:

```
template <class Algorithm, class Range>
void time_sort(Algorithm algo, Range&& range)
{
    using std::begin;
    using std::end;

    // start timer
    algo(begin(first), end(last));
    // stop timer
    // do stuff with the difference
}
```

And then you just write a bunch of different function objects that implement the various sorts you want to time. The standard library version of this would be something like:

```
struct StdSort {
    template <class Iterator>
    void operator()(Iterator first, Iterator last) {
        std::sort(first, last);
    }
};
```

and then you'd use that function template like:

```
time_it(StdSort{}, gimme_vector<int>());
time_it(StdSort{}, gimme_list<Foo>());
```

If you want to test new sorting algorithms, just create a new types:

```
struct MergeSort {
    template <class Iterator>
    void operator()(Iterator first, Iterator last) {
        // ...
    }
};

struct StackOverflowSort {
    template <class Iterator>
    void operator()(Iterator first, Iterator last) {
        // see xkcd 1185
    }
};
```

And pass that in as the first argument. Rinse and repeat.

```
time_sort(MergeSort{}, gimme_vector<int>());
time_sort(StackOverflowSort{}, gimme_list<Foo>());
```

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to write such elaborate answer. It does look like a "true c++ way of doing this". It feels kind of like anti-pattern to me (OOP-wise), but I guess it can't be helped.

Comment: @user2521472 OOP is itself almost always an anti-pattern.